# Checking if a download link is working without downloading the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way in Javascript (and jQuery) to check if a URL is status 200 (specifically not 404) without downloading it's contents if it is in fact status 200?

For example, I want to check if a download link to a video works before executing some code. The issue when I use `$.ajax()` is that when the link does in fact work, it will only notify me AFTER the download has finished. In a way is there a way to just "ping" the url to see if it works without getting it's contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), which should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
jQuery.ajax({type: "HEAD", url: "http://google.com/"})
```

This type of request is mainly used by browsers to check cache validity, but it also should work here.

Comment: Always glad to help :) If my answer did indeed solve your problem, I'd be delighted if you could accept my answer by clicking that check mark on the left...

Comment: Ya there was like a time limit before I could click it or something. It's good now!